# Python regex extract MAC addresses from string

Tags: python, regex

I need help writing a regular expression, using the python `re` engine to:

1. Extract all MAC addresses from a text file
2. Extract all strings with the following format: `foo bar ... MAC:ADDRESS ... baz bat \r\n`

Thanks in advance!

I tried the following to extract MAC addresses, without luck:

```python
import re
p = re.compile(ur'((?:(\d{1,2}|[a-fA-F]{1,2}){2})(?::|-*)){6}')
test_str = u"TEXT WITH SOME MAC ADDRESSES 00:24:17:b1:cc:cc TEXT CONTINUES WITH SOME MORE TEXT 20:89:86:9a:86:24"

found = re.findall(p, test_str)
for a in found:
    print a
```

Comment: If you have regex questions, providing several example inputs and expected outputs helps tremendously.

Comment: Thank you @vks ... any idea guys? :/ I am really confused with regex..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have concocted the following: `([0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}` to match MAC addresses in the text.

Here is how it is supposed to work:

- `[0-9a-fA-F]` matches the characters used to represent hexadecimal numbers
- `:?` matches an optional colon
- `(...){12}` - all of this is then grouped and repeated 12 times. 12 because a MAC address consists of 6 pairs of hexadecimal numbers, separated by a colon

You can see it in action [here](http://regex101.com/r/bD4eT9/2) .

The Python code then becomes:

```python
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:[0-9a-fA-F]:?){12}')
test_str = u"TEXT WITH SOME MAC ADDRESSES 00:24:17:b1:cc:cc TEXT CONTINUES WITH SOME MORE TEXT 20:89:86:9a:86:24"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Producing as a result:

```python
[u'00:24:17:b1:cc:cc', u'20:89:86:9a:86:24']
```

Comment: Thanks, but why can't i print the whole mac after findall?

Comment: Changed it to use a non-matching group. Should work now.

Comment: Once you can match the MAC addresses you can solve the second part of your problem too. [FYI this is a great website to test your regexps.](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: @SlothGR this is incorrect for matching mac address.see here http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/7

Comment: @vks I tried the regexp and it seems to work (see the link provided). Why do you think it is incorrect? Moreover, I checked your regexp and it works too. That's the beauty of StackOverflow: there is no *unique* answer.

Comment: mac address has a specific format.And your regex does not validate it correctly.It vaildates too many other strings as well.See d link i posted.They are no mac addresses but still get parsed

Answer (score 9):

```
([0-9a-f]{2}(?::[0-9a-f]{2}){5})
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP8uF5/5

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'([0-9a-f]{2}(?::[0-9a-f]{2}){5})', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"TEXT WITH SOME MAC ADDRESSES 00:24:17:b1:cc:cc TEXT CONTINUES WITH SOME MORE TEXT 20:89:86:9a:86:24"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to match MAC addresses too and this worked:`((?:[\da-fA-F]{2}[:\-]){5}[\da-fA-F]{2})`

I tested it with this live regex tester: https://regex101.com/#python 
It had a very nice breakdown of what each piece of regex did.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "this is aa:bb:cc:dd:01:02 test for aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff and AABBCCDDEEFF is a mac address without separator"
```

let us extract mac addresses

```
def extract_mac_address(text):
    pattern = '(([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[:]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|([0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-]){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})|[0-9a-fA-F]{12})'
    mac_addr_list = re.findall(pattern, text)
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0], mac_addr_list))


print(extract_mac_address(text))
```

and output is `['aa:bb:cc:dd:01:02', 'aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff', 'AABBCCDDEEFF']`

Answer (score 0):

Best regex match of a single MAC address without overflow at the end:

```
import re

regex = r"^((([a-f0-9]{2}:){5})|(([a-f0-9]{2}-){5}))[a-f0-9]{2}$"

test_str = "89:89:89:89:89:89"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 1, re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Ref: https://regexpattern.com/mac-address/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Kinda unrelated but i stumbled across this and i found a solution

```
mac_pattern = r"\b\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w\b"
mac_pattern2 = r"\b\w\w.\w\w.\w\w.\w\w.\w\w.\w\w\b"
```

so it reads as such:

1. word boundary
2. two word characters
3. a dash
4. two word characters
5. dash
6. two word characters
7. dash
8. two word characters
9. dash
10. two word characters
11. dash
12. two word characters
13. word boundary.

This works for arp -a in windows 10. Obviously just swap out the dashes for the semicolons in your case.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
print(re.search("([a-f0-9A-F]{4}[.]){2}[a-f0-9A-F]{4}", "0000.aaaa.bbbb").group())

[a-f0-9A-F]{4} -> matches for four occurrences of a-f or 0-9, A-F 

here it will search only for one mac in a string.if you want to search for more than one occurance we need to use re.findall.
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Code-only answers are of limited usefulness without an explanation of how they solve the problem.

Comment: if you want to search for more than one mac address we need to use re.findall and also edited regex to avoid matching non hex-digits

Answer (score -1):

The best way to find the valid MAC addresses from any input is:

`r'([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})[\s]'`

Comment: Why is this "the best way"? Apart from the `[\s]` (which you fail to provide any explanation for) and the gratuitous square brackets around that and the colon, this just duplicates previous answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).